# How to send data from gmail to different sheets based on date?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a script that runs in a google sheet that parses emails and creates new lines in the sheet.  This is used to create a log file from periodically emailed log updates.  This works very well.

Currently, I have a variable that is used to determine which emails are ingested based on the month (0=January, etc.)

That variable has to be adjusted every month and then I have to create a new monthly sheet (tab in the main) and do a bunch of sorting and moving emails in gmail.

I'd like to set this up so it automatically puts the January emails in a sheet for January and the February emails in a sheet for February.

I thought about cascading if elseif statements, but that got too unwieldy fast.

I thought about iterating using a for loop through an array holding all emails, but that seems convoluted too.

Any suggestions?

::EDIT::
To be clear, I'm really interested in how to parse all of the emails and send the ones from January to the January sheet (for example).

::EDIT:: Added current script

```js
    function myFunction() {
        var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(myLabel);
        var label2 = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(newLabel);
        var threads = label.getThreads();
        var data = new Array();
        var newData = new Array();

        // get all the email threads matching myLabel
        for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);

            // archive thread
            label2.addToThread(threads[i]);
            label.removeFromThread(threads[i]);

            // get each individual email from the threads
            for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++) {
                var bodyText = messages[j].getPlainBody();

                // split the email body into individual "paragraph" strings based on the regExp variable
                while (matches = regExp.exec(bodyText)) {
                    var logdata = matches[1];
                    for (k in keys) {
                        logdata = logdata.replace(keys[k], "");
                    }

                    // split out each "paragraph" string into an array
                    var lines = logdata.split(/[\r\n]+/);
                    for (l in lines) {
                      lines[l] = lines[l].replace('*F','');
                      lines[l] = lines[l].trim();
                    }
                    for (l in lines) {
                        lines[l] = lines[l].replace(/^(\:\s)/, "");
                    }

                    // Turn the first element in the array into a date element, format it, and put it back
                    lines[0] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(lines[0]), "America/Phoenix", "M/d/yy HH:mm:ss");

                    // Put the array to a new item in the data array for further processing
                    if (curMonth == (new Date(lines[0]).getMonth())) {
                        data.push(lines);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Compare the information in the data array to oldData information in the sheet
      if (data.length) {
        var oldData = s.getRange(range).getValues();
        for (h in oldData) {
          oldData[h][0] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(oldData[h][0]), "America/Phoenix", "M/d/yy HH:mm:ss");
        }
        for (i in data) {
          var row = data[i];
          var duplicate = false;
          for (j in oldData) {
            if (row.join() == oldData[j].join()) {
              duplicate = true;
            }
          }
          if (!duplicate) {
            newData.push(row);
          }
        }
        // check to write newData only if there is newData, this stops an error when newData is empty
        if (newData.length) {
          s.getRange(s.getLastRow() + 1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
        }
        s.getRange(range).sort(1); //sorts the sheet
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getSheet(date) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetId');
  var name=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMyyyy")
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(name);
  if(!sh) {
    var sh=ss.insertSheet(name);
  }
  return sh;
}
```

Comment: So that opens a spreadsheet, creates "name" as JUN2019 (for example), checks for that sheet name, and if it isn't there, creates it. Correct?

What would be the most elegant way to parse all of the emails into them?

Comment: That's correct.  I think you would just get the email date and do getSheet( emaildate).appendRow([recipient,from,message,...etc]).  But there's a lot of different ways.

Comment: Thanks heaps Cooper.  I'll give it a shot.  I've added my current script to the original question above.  The way it processes messages makes me concerned that it won't be so easy.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up basing my solution on the solution that @cooper provided, but had to go a little further.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var month = new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
var curMonth = new Date().getMonth(); //number of month -1 aka: January = 0
var sheetname = month[curMonth] + " " + new Date().getYear();
var s = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

function newMonth(){
  if (!s) {
    var template = ss.getSheetByName('Template').copyTo(ss);
    template.setName(sheetname);
    s = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname); //"reload" the sheet
    s.showSheet(); //unhide the new copy since 'Template' is hidden in the spreadsheet
    ss.setActiveSheet(s);  //make it active
    ss.moveActiveSheet(0); //move it to the first position
  }
}
```